# Variance of product of dependent variables

Tags: correlation, variance

What is the formula for variance of product of dependent variables?

In the case of independent variables the formula is simple:

$$ \operatorname{var}(XY) = E(X^2Y^2) - E(XY)^2 = \operatorname{var}(X) \operatorname{var}(Y) + \operatorname{var}(X)E(Y)^2 + \operatorname{var}(Y) E(X)^2 $$
But what is the formula for correlated variables?

By the way, how can I find the correlation based on the statistical data?

Comment: When you write `{\rm var}` instead of `\operatorname{var}` you set a bad example. These `\rm` lacks context-dependent spacing, so you'll see things like $2{\rm var}(X)$ instead of $2\operatorname{var}(X)$, and if you omit the parentheses and write $\operatorname{var}X$ then `\rm` will cause you to see instead ${\rm var}X. \qquad$

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, using the familiar identity you pointed out,

$$ \operatorname{var}(XY) = E(X^2Y^2) - E(XY)^2 $$

Using the analogous formula for covariance,

$$ E(X^2Y^2) = \operatorname{cov}(X^2, Y^2) + E(X^2)E(Y^2) $$

and

$$ E(XY)^2 = [ \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) + E(X)E(Y) ]^2 $$

which implies that, in general, ${\rm var}(XY)$ can be written as

$$ {\rm cov}(X^2, Y^2) + [\operatorname{var}(X) + E(X)^2] \cdot[\operatorname{var}(Y) + E(Y)^2] - [ \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) + E(X)E(Y) ]^2  $$

Note that in the independence case, $\operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2) = \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = 0$ and this reduces to

$$ [\operatorname{var}(X) + E(X)^2] \cdot[\operatorname{var}(Y) + E(Y)^2] - [ E(X)E(Y) ]^2  $$

and the two $[ E(X)E(Y) ]^2 $ terms cancel out and you get

$$ \operatorname{var}(X)\operatorname{var}(Y) + \operatorname{var}(X)E(Y)^2 + \operatorname{var}(Y)E(X)^2 $$

as you pointed out above.

**Edit:** If all you observe is $XY$ and not $X$ and $Y$ separately, then I don't think there is a way for you to estimate $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$ or $\operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2)$ except in special cases (for example, if $X,Y$ have means that are known *a priori*)

Comment: why do you put [var(X)+E(X)2]⋅[var(Y)+E(Y)2] instead of E(X2)E(Y2)???

Comment: @user35458, so he can end up with the equation as an expression of var(X) and var(Y), thus comparable to OP's statement. Notice that E(X ^ 2) = Var(X) + E(X) ^ 2.

Comment: In order to respond (offline) to a now-deleted challenge to the validity of this answer, I compared its results to direct calculation of the variance of the product in many simulations.  It's not a practical formula to use if you can avoid it, because it can lose substantial precision through cancellation in subtracting one large term from another--but that's not the point.  One pitfall to beware is that this question concerns *random variables.*  Its results apply to data *provided you compute variances and covariances using denominators of $n$ rather than $n-1$* (as is usual for software).

Comment: When you write `{\rm var}` instead of `\operatorname{var}` you set a bad example. These `\rm` lacks context-dependent spacing, so you'll see things like $2{\rm var}(X)$ instead of $2\operatorname{var}(X)$, and if you omit the parentheses and write $\operatorname{var}X$ then `\rm` will cause you to see instead ${\rm var}X. \qquad$

Answer (score 18):

This is an *addendum* to @Macro's very nice answer which lays out
exactly what needs to known in order to determine the variance of
the product of two correlated random variables. Since
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(XY) &= E\left[(XY)^2\right] - \left(E[XY]\right)^2
\tag{1}\\
&= E[(XY)^2] - \left(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+E[X]E[Y]\right)^2\\
&= E[X^2Y^2] - \left(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+E[X]E[Y]\right)^2\tag{2}\\
&= \left(\operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2)+E[X^2]E[Y^2]\right)
- \left(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+E[X]E[Y]\right)^2\tag{3}\\
\end{align}
where $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, $E[X]$, $E[Y]$, $E[X^2]$, and
$E[Y^2]$  can be assumed to
be known quantities, we need to be able to determine the value of
$E\left[X^2Y^2\right]$ in $(2)$ or $\operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2)$ in $(3)$.
This is not easy to do in general, but, as pointed out already, if
$X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables, then
$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = \operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2) = 0$.
In fact, *dependence,* not correlation (or lack thereof) is the
key issue. That we know that $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$ equals $0$
instead of some nonzero value does not, *by itself,* help in the
least in our efforts are determining the value of
$E\left[X^2Y^2\right]$ or $\operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2)$ even though it
*does* simplify the right sides of $(2)$ and $(3)$ a little.

When $X$ and $Y$ are *dependent*
random variables, then in at least one (fairly common
or fairly important) special
case, it *is* possible to find
the value of $E\left[X^2Y^2\right]$ relatively easily.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly normal* random variables
with correlation coefficient $\rho$. Then, *conditioned*
on $X = x$, the *conditional* density of $Y$ is a normal
density with mean
$E[Y] + \rho\left.\left.\sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{var}(Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)}}
\right(x-E[X]\right)$ and variance $\operatorname{var}(Y)(1-\rho^2)$. Thus,
\begin{align}E[X^2Y^2 \mid X] &= X^2E[Y^2 \mid X]\\
&= X^2\left[\operatorname{var}(Y)(1-\rho^2)
+ \left(E[Y] + \rho\left.\left.\sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{var}(Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)}}
\right(X-E[X]\right)\right)^2\right]
\end{align}
which is a *quartic* function of $X$, say $g(X)$, and the Law of Iterated
Expectation tells us that
$$E[X^2Y^2] = E\left[E[X^2Y^2\mid X]\right] = E[g(X)]\tag{4}$$
where the right side of $(4)$ can be computed from knowledge of the
3rd and 4th moments of $X$ -- standard results that can be found
in many texts and reference books
(meaning that I am too lazy to look them up
and include them in this answer). Fortunately, Moderator whuber has gone a step further and provided the exact result for the variance of $XY$ in a recent comment on this answer:
$$\operatorname{var}(XY) =(\mu_Y\sigma_X)^2 + (\mu_X\sigma_Y)^2 + (1+\rho^2)(\sigma_X\sigma_Y)^2 +2\rho\mu_X\mu_Y\sigma_X\sigma_Y.\tag{4}$$
Notice that when $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables, Eq. $(4)$ reduces to
$$\operatorname{var}(XY) =(\mu_Y\sigma_X)^2 + (\mu_X\sigma_Y)^2 + \sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2 \tag{5}$$
which is just what the OP and Macro wrote but expressed in slightly different notation.

---

Further addendum: In a now-deleted answer, @Hydrologist gives the variance of $XY$ as
$$\mathrm{Var}\left[xy\right] = \left(\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]\right)^2\mathrm{Var}\left[y\right] + \left(\mathrm{E}\left[y\right]\right)^2\mathrm{Var}\left[x\right] + 2\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]\mathrm{Cov}\left[x,y^2\right] + 2\mathrm{E}\left[y\right]\mathrm{Cov}\left[x^2,y\right]\\ + 2\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]\mathrm{E}\left[y\right]\mathrm{Cov}\left[x,y\right] +\mathrm{Cov}\left[x^2,y^2\right] - \left(\mathrm{Cov}\left[x,y\right]\right)^2 \tag{5}$$
and claims that this formula is from two papers published a half-century ago in JASA. This formula is an incorrect transcription of the results in the paper(s) cited by Hydrologist. Specifically, $\mathrm{Cov}\left[x^2,y^2\right]$ is a mistranscription of
$E[(x-E[x])^2(y-E[y])^2]$ in the journal article, and similarly for $\mathrm{Cov}\left[x^2,y\right]$ and $\mathrm{Cov}\left[x,y^2\right]$.

Comment: For the computation of $E(X^2 Y^2)$ in the joint normal case, also see 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668641/covariance-of-two-chi-square-random-variables

Comment: In terms of the means, SDs, and correlation coefficient of the binormal distribution, the variance of the product can be expressed as $$\operatorname{Var}(XY)=(\mu_Y\sigma_X)^2 + (\mu_X\sigma_Y)^2 + (\sigma_X\sigma_Y)^2(1 + \rho^2) + 2 \mu_X\mu_Y\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho.$$

Comment: @whuber Thanks. Since comments can be ephemeral, and worse yet, skipped over by many readers, I have incorporated your formula into my answer (with credit to you, of course.)