# Sample Variance of Power of Sample Mean

Tags: variance, mean

I would like to know whether it is possible to derive a closed-form expression for the sample variance of the $n$-th power of the sample mean $\overline{x}_m$ that was calculated using $m$ sample values $x_i$:

$\mathrm{Var}[\overline{x}_m^n] =\;?$,

where

$\overline{x}_m = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m x_i$.

It is clear that in case of $m=1$, $\overline{x}_1 = x_1$, for which [this solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232391) can be used.
However, I am interested in a general solution for $m > 1$, preferably for arbitrarily distributed samples, but I expect that to be challenging or even impossible.
So, I would also be happy with a solution for normally distributed samples.

**Update #1:** I think that I have used the term *closed-form expression* incorrectly and might have been too unprecise in general. Let me clarify: I am basically looking for a **formula** to calculate a good (preferably unbiased) **estimate** for $\mathrm{Var}[\overline{x}_m^n]$ based sample values $x_i$.

A comment indicated that for normally distributed $x_i$, $\overline{x}_m$ is still normally distributed and as such, the solution should be trivial.
However, I still would like to have a formula to estimate the variance $\mathrm{Var}[\overline{x}_m^n]$based on the given set of samples values $x_i$.

Apologies for the misleading initial question.

Comment: I do not think there is general solution. For normal, $\bar x_m$ is still normal and you already have the answer.

Comment: I think you really want the _population_ variance of blah  i.e. Var(blah)--- not the _sample_ variance of blah. There can be no closed-form expression for the sample variance other than the sample variance of blah.

Comment: @user158565 Thanks for the hint! You're correct, however, I have updated the original question in order to clarify what I'm really interested in.

Comment: @wolfies I'm afraid that I actually wanted something entirely different. I have updated the question accordingly. Thank you for contributing to the quality of the question.

Comment: From your link, it seems you are working though mgf. Then see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912869/moment-generating-function-of-a-sum-of-i-i-d-random-variables, maybe you can get answer from there.