# Var(XY), if X and Y are independent random variables

Tags: distributions, variance, random-variable

if X and Y are independent Random variable then what is the variance of XY?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about this yourself? $\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)$ would be wrong - consider an almost surely constant non-zero $X$

Comment: No sir. I know Var(XY)= E(X^2 Y^2)- (E(XY))^2 and E(XY)= E(X) E(Y) as X, Y are independent  but no idea about X^2 and Y^2 are independent or not.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are also independent and $E[X^2Y^2]=E[X^2]E[Y^2]$

Comment: General product case here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52646/variance-of-product-of-multiple-random-variables (product of 2 is given in the question)

Answer (score 10):

You can follow Henry's comments to arrive at the answer. However, another way to come to the answer is to use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $Y | X = Y$ and $X |Y = X$.

By iterated expectations and variance expressions

\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(XY) & = \text{Var}[\,\text{E}(XY|X)\,] + \text{E}[\,\text{Var}(XY|X) \,]\\
& = \text{Var}[\,X\, \text{E}(Y|X)\,] + E[\,X^2\, \text{Var}(Y|X)\,]\\
& = \text{Var}[\,X\, \text{E}(Y)\,] + E[\,X^2\, \text{Var}(Y)\,]\\
& = E(Y)^2\, \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) E(X^2)\,.
\end{align*}

Comment: $E(Y)^2\, \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) E(X^2)$ may be correct, but it is strangely non-symmetric as $E(Y^2)\, \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) E(X)^2$ would be.  I would have thought $\text{Var}(X)E(Y)^2  + \text{Var}(Y) E(X)^2 +\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)$ would be more natural while $\text{Var}(X)E(Y^2)  + \text{Var}(Y) E(X^2) -\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)$ would also be true

Comment: @Henry Well, using $E(X^2) = Var(X) + E(X)^2$, we get $Var(XY) = E(Y)^2Var(X) + Var(Y)Var(X) + Var(Y) E(X)^2$. That's symmetric.