# Standard deviation/variance for the sum, product and quotient of two Poisson distributions

Tags: dataset, poisson-distribution, error, poisson-regression, error-propagation

What would be the standard deviation for $A+B$, $AB$ and $\frac{A}{B}$ for $A$ and $B$ Poisson distributed?

Comment: What do you mean by "error"? Are you looking for the variance, or the standard deviation? Also, what is your first distribution you are interested in? (The second is $AB$, the third is $\frac{A}{B}$ - note that the third one is not defined, because $B$ has a nonzero probability of being zero.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am looking for std dev. I am working on Gamma Ray data, so that corresponds to the Poisson distribution, so the error or the std dev is the sqrt(data value) , so what would be these qts asked above?

Comment: OK, so by "error" you mean the standard deviation, good. What do you mean by "2 data A and B"? Are you looking for the standard deviation of a random variable $A+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both Poisson (and presumably independent)?

Comment: yes ! I'll edit the question, I think that was the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. Please do edit the question, so later users can find it easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will assume that $A\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $B\sim\text{Pois}(\mu)$ are independent Poisson variables. Then

$$ EA=\text{var} A=\lambda\quad\text{and}\quad EB=\text{var} B=\mu. $$

1. Let's consider $A+B$. It's a standard property of the Poisson distribution that the sum of independent Poisson variables is again Poisson, with a parameter that is just the sum of the separate Poisson parameters:

$$ A+B\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda+\mu). $$

Thus,

$$ \text{sd}(A+B)=\sqrt{\text{var}(A+B)} = \sqrt{\lambda+\mu}. $$

2. Let's consider the product $AB$. This distribution [does not have a specific name](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/272099/51074), but we can derive its variance from [the general formula for the variance of a product distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/52646/1352):
   $$
     \text{var}(AB) =\text{var}A\,\text{var}B+\text{var}A(EB)^2+(EA)^2\text{var}B
     = \lambda\mu+\lambda\mu^2+\lambda^2\mu, $$
   so the standard deviation is just
   $$ \text{sd}(AB) = \sqrt{\text{var}(AB)} = \sqrt{\lambda\mu+\lambda\mu^2+\lambda^2\mu}. $$
   I like verifying things like this by a quick simulation. In R:

   ```
    n_sims <- 1e6
    lambda <- mu <- c(0.5,1,2)
    observed <- expected <- matrix(nrow=length(lambda),ncol=length(mu),dimnames=list(lambda,mu))
    for ( ii in seq_along(lambda) ) {
        for ( jj in seq_along(mu) ) {
            set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
        observed[ii,jj] <- var(rpois(n_sims,lambda[ii])*rpois(n_sims,mu[jj]))
        expected[ii,jj] <- lambda[ii]*mu[jj]+lambda[ii]*mu[jj]^2+lambda[ii]^2*mu[jj]
        }
    }
    observed
    expected
   ```

   yields

   ```
    > observed
              0.5        1         2
    0.5 0.4945624 1.232162  3.470369
    1   1.2362181 2.959398  7.946589
    2   3.4516277 7.870455 19.795708
    > expected
         0.5    1    2
    0.5 0.50 1.25  3.5
    1   1.25 3.00  8.0
    2   3.50 8.00 20.0
   ```

   as expected.
3. Finally, how about $\frac{A}{B}$? This is not a well-defined distribution, since $P(A\neq 0, B=0)\neq 0$, and we would divide by zero.