# Given that X and Y are normally distributed as N(0,3) and N(0,5) respectively, what is the expected value of (XY)^2?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Given that X and Y are independent and normally distributed as N(0,3) and N(0,5) respectively, what is the expected value of (XY)^2?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @Henry yes, they are

Answer (score 7):

The trick here is to rewrite the expected value in terms of several rules that you have learned in class. Maybe the following rules ring a bell:

- $E[XY] = E[X]\cdot E[Y] \quad \text{if $X$ and $Y$ are independent}$
- $E[X^2] = \text{Var}[X]+ E[X]^2$

Comment: One more rule is needed  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52646/variance-of-product-of-multiple-independent-random-variables

Comment: @Jacques That extra rule is not needed and applying it only complicates the solution.  Another one that is used implicitly is that [functions of independent variables (separately) remain independent.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/) For this specific question I would point out that $E[X^2]=\operatorname{Var}(X)$ because $E[X]=0.$ That eliminates all probability calculations and allows one to write down the answer immediately, depending on how "N(0,3)" is interpreted (is its variance $3$ or $9$?).  (+1)

Comment: @JacquesWainer: The more useful rule is that $(XY)^2 = X^2Y^2$.