# Covariance of two variables that are products of shared random variables

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, covariance

How to analytically express cov(X,Y), when:

```
X=C*A/(A+B)
```

and

```
Y=C*B/(A+B)
```

Here C, A and B are independent variables with normal distributions.

More specifically I would like to express cov(X,Y) using the expected means of each of the input variables C, A and B, as well as their standard deviations or variances.

```
A is a normal distribution with an expected mean E(A) and a variance var(A)
B is a normal distribution with an expected mean E(B) and a variance var(B)
C is a normal distribution with an expected mean E(C) and a variance var(C)
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: if this is HW please add the self-study tag

Comment: Thank you for asking but it is for my research at work. I have really searched a lot the last few days for the answer, but I can only find examples where X and Y are linear combinations of random variables like X=aA+bB+cC (with small a, b and c as constants) but I cannot find solutions where X is a function that is the product of a combination of A, B and C.

Comment: I think that would help if you could show some of those examples you refer to and then explain how it is different in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. 
The question ressembles a bit this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137571/covariance-of-product , but the example in the link is in matrix notation and it is not clear for me if Xi and Xj in the example are correlated, so I cannot used this directly.

Comment: `Here C, A and B are independent variables with a normal distribution` ... the same Normal distribution (e.g. standard Normal), or with differing means and variances?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was not being clear. A, B and C have different means and variances.

Comment: Given that this involves the ratio of Normals, convergence may be an issue

Comment: OK. Just for curiosity, would it be easier/possible to solve a simplified problem, and express cov(X,Y) if X=A*C and Y=B*C?

Comment: Well, that's a different question, but by quick calculation, the answer would be:  $\text{Cov}( A C, BC) = \mu _a \mu _b \sigma _c^2$

Answer (score 5):

One can find a general solution, without assuming Normality. In particular, if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent, and noting that the Covariance operator is the {1,1} central moment, then $\text{Cov}( \frac{C A}{A+B},\frac{C B}{A+B})$ is:

[image]

where I am using a developmental version of the `CentralMomentToCentral` function in *mathStatica* (alas, not in any public release yet).

The reason the solution does not converge (assuming Normal parents) is because $A+B$ is Normal, and thus $E[\frac{1}{A+B}]$ is the expectation of the inverse of a Normal variable, which is known not to converge (see, for instance, [Mean and variance of inverse of a normal RV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70045/mean-and-variance-of-inverse-of-a-normal-rv))

Comment: Thank you so much Wolfies! It is extremely helpful to see your answer, and I really appreciate that you took your time to work with this problem. Now I try to implement the result in my calculations and compare with the simulations :-) 

The mathStatica seems like a really powerful tool.

Comment: Just one little question, I see that the C in your code has a different colour than A and B. Is there any reason for this?