# Comparison of two Products of Variance

Tags: variance, covariance, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$, $B$ and $B'$ be random variables, and consider

$\text{Var}(AB) \text{ and} \text{ Var}(AB')$,

such that $\text{Cov}(A,B)\ne 0$, $\text{Cov}(A,B')\ne 0$ and $\text{Var}(B)\geq \text{Var}(B')$.

Then, we might conclude that $\text{Var}(AB)\geq \text{Var}(AB')$.

I have been trying to verify this, but this is pretty difficult.

Does anyone have a nice clue of how to do this?

Comment: Start with looking at [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15986/6633) which gives an explicit formula for the variance of the product of two non-independent random variables. It might give a clue as to why you are having difficulty proving what you want to prove, such as the result does not hold in general.....

Comment: Yes, I've already seen that answer, so complicated. But in my question, there is a helpful hint that $Var(B)\geq Var(B')$. With this, it might lead us to  my potential conclusion.

Comment: But the correct answer, which you might have seen but apparently have not understood, includes terms such as $\operatorname{cov}(A^2, B^2)$ whose value is unknown and cannot be determined from the additional assumptions that you make. So, go to it, and find a proof that leads to your desired conclusion using just the additional assumptions that you have already made. But, don't expect me to believe your proof.

Comment: Well I know what you point out, however the additional codition would help us to at least \it {approximate} my desired inequality