# cov(x,x*y) Covariance of two normally distributed variables

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, bivariate

I have been trying to find an expression for the covariance of two normally distributed variables $X$ and $Y$ if $cov(X,Y)=c$ then $cov(X,XY)=?$

I would greatly appreciate any help. Probably it must be something very simple that i am missing

Comment: Hint: First, you need to know something about the _joint_ distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Try to find the _conditional_ covariance of $X$ and $XY$ conditioned on $Y = y$. Then find the unconditional covariance of $X$ and $XY$

Comment: Thank you. What I did might seem illogical but basically
Cov(x,xy)=E(x^2*y)-E(x)E(xy)
Then
E(x^2)E(y)+cov(x^2,y)=var(x)E(y)+2E(x)cov[x,y]

Using steins lemma for second term above 

And doing same thing for E(xy)
I get express everything with two variables and no multiplication. 
But not sure if I am doing the right thing

Comment: I have no idea how you get to the second equation in your comment from the first one, and you _still_ don't seem to understand my point about the _joint_ distribution of $X$ and $Y$. For the case of _independent_ $X$ and $Y$ (whether normal or not), I show in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/340131/6633) that $\operatorname{cov}(X,XY)=\operatorname{var}(X)E[Y]$. For _jointly normal_ but  _dependent_  $X$ and $Y$ , one can say more

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly binormal, then the joint moment generating function of $(X,Y)$ is
$$
M(s,t)=\exp(\mu_X s + \mu_Y t + \sigma_X^2 s^2/2 + \sigma_Y^2 t^2/2 + c st),
$$
where $c=\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.  From this you can work out
$$E(X^2 Y) 
  = \frac{\partial^3}{\partial s^2\partial t}M(s,t)|_{s=0,t=0}
$$
and 
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X,XY)=E(X^2Y)-EXE(XY)
$$
in terms of $\mu_X$, $\mu_Y$, $\sigma_X$, $\sigma_Y$ and $c$.

Comment: But note, as also pointed out by @DilipSarwate, that the joint distribution is not known from the assumptions you are making.